# Django searches for a template in an unspecified location

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

In the `base.html`,

```
<a href="/login">Log In</a>
```

In the main `urls.py`,

```
from ...
from accounts.views import login_view, logout_view, register_view
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^login/', login_view),
    ....
]
```

In the accounts`views.py`,

```
def login_view (request):
    request.session.set_expiry(request.session.get_expiry_age())
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    title = "Login"
    if form.is_valid() : 
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request,user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    return render(request, 'accounts/login_form.html',{ "form" : form, "title": title})
```

When the `Log In` is clicked, the `login_form` template is searched in `'registration/login.html'` instead of `'accounts/login_form.html'`.

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/***/Desktop/django/mysite/personal/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/***/Desktop/django/mysite/blog/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/***/Desktop/django/mysite/landing/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/***/Desktop/django/mysite/accounts/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/crispy_forms/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pagedown/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/markdown_deux/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tracking/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/registration/login.html (Source does not exist)
```

All of this was working fine until I tried over-ridding `registration/password_reset_form.html`, `registration/password_reset_done.html`, `registration/password_reset_confirm.html`,
`registration/password_reset_complete.html` to achieve password reset functionality.

The main `urls.py` had included,

```
url(r'^user/password/reset/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset',{'post_reset_redirect' : '/user/password/reset/done/'},name="password_reset"),
url(r'^user/password/reset/done/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done'),
url(r'^user/password/reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm',{'post_reset_redirect' : '/user/password/done/'}),
url(r'^user/password/done/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),
```

Any suggestions ? Thanks !

**Edit** : The template is searched in correct location only when `/login`,`/logout`, and `/register` are not used as url path. I tried using `/user_login`, `/user_logout`, and `/user_register` and it worked. I think it's conflicting with the inbuilt login of `urls.py`. How to correct this ?

Comment: are you using any third party packages for login ?

Comment: @itzmeontv : No third party..Got the solution. Have posted it as an answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had `url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))` mentioned above `login` and other urls. This is the reason, Django was looking for a template under `/registration/login`. I still don't know why Django looks for a template in that location when the url is `/login`. When the url is `accounts/login`, no problems occur. I put `url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))`in the end of urlpatterns.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from accounts.views import login_view, logout_view, register_view, reset_password_view

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('personal.urls')), 
    url(r'^login/', login_view),
    url(r'^logout/', logout_view),
    url(r'^register/', register_view),
    url(r'^reset-password/', reset_password_view),
    url(r'^landing/', include('landing.urls')),
    url(r'^tracking/', include('tracking.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),  # Put this in the end 
]
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you should create `urls.py` for your app `accounts`?

accounts `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /accounts/
    url(r'^login/', login_view),
]
```

in the main `urls.py`

```
from ...
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^accounts/', include('yourwebsite.accounts.urls')),
    ....
]
```

and `base.html`

```
<a href="/accounts/login">Log In</a>
```

Comment: Thanks.. I changed it to `accounts/login` to avoid further issues.